# Какую архитектуру применить для следующей задачи на laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Есть проект, в нем такие роли - админ, врач, клиент.
У клиента своя анкета, у врача своя. Про RBAC вопросов не задаю, тут мы просто раскидаем на users, roles и role_user

**Главный вопрос** - если мы врачей и клиентов храним в одной таблице, как лучше хранить их анкеты?

Ведь у врача есть обязательное поле - ***специализация***, например. У клиента его нет, зато есть свое специальное поле, к примеру, это ***хронические болезни***.

Какие варианты вижу я:

1. Все затолкать в одну таблицу (users), нужное подтягивать в зависимости от ситуации. Минус в том, что это бардак в чистом виде - одна таблица двоих еще вместит, а что если там 3-4-5 ролей? Там уже будет хлам.
2. Сделать поле анкета json-ом. Тут тебе и компактность, и нет смешения, но json достаточно недавно в sql для меня, не знаю точно, где его юзать. Да и поиск становится чуть замороченнее.
3. Просто сделать users как базовая модель, а от нее наследовать другие модели - clients и doctors. Тут надо разобраться - как такое сделать и как решать вопрос с авторизацией и как внутри связи устроены? Если этот вариант годный, буду его копать.
4. Увести профили в отдельные таблицы, например, client_profiles и doctor_profiles. Но как тогда корректно прокинуть связь так, чтобы у докторов не было client_profiles (пусть и null'евого), а у клиентов doctor_profiles?..
5. Вышеописанное еще можно сделать так - сделать таблицу profile_attributes, и построчно выставлять соответствие между атрибутом профайла и значением для каждого конкретного юзера - клиента или доктора, не важно.

Короче, понимаю, что варианты есть разные, есть мною не описанные, но хотелось бы понять, какие в этом вопросе **best practics**

Comment: Вот отличный гайд по моему вопросу, автору респект!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691577/how-can-i-implement-single-table-inheritance-using-laravels-eloquent

Answer (score 1):

Все эти вопросы достаточно подробно рассмотрены в книге "Шаблоны корпоративных приложений" Мартин Фаулер и др. (Single Table Inheritance, 297) и далее по ссылкам внутри книги на другие варианты

Данный вопрос вне языка программирования и тем более вне реализации ORM(точнее все эти реализации построены на описанных в этой книге подходах)

Если все же выбирать, то я за Class Table Inheritance(по сути ваш вариант 3), он и держит по полочкам структуру данных и связи можно наладить по обстоятельствам(где нужен FK на абстракцию - значит на абстрактную users, а если только связь присуща на докторов - то на таблицу с докторами)

Оптимизацией уже стоит заниматься после замеров. И да чтобы не попасть в просак с ORM почитайте так же книжки по DDD (например "красную книгу" Вернон Вона "Реализация методов предметно-ориентированного проектирования")

У Фаулера кстати есть отличная фраза относительно стратегии мапинга таблиц в объекты... "Напомню: вы вовсе не обязаны использовать единственную форму отображения для всей иерархии наследования. Например, вы можете применить наследование с таблицами для каждого класса для классов, находящихся на верхних уровнях иерархии, и несколько наследований с таблицами для каждого конкретного класса для классов на более низких уровнях. "

Comment: Что самое интересное - книгу купил, прочитать забыл :) Вы не могли бы в двух словах сказать, какой подход был бы наиболее успешным при вышеописанной задаче? К сожалению, не располагаю временем очень глубоко уходить в эту тему.

Comment: Я Вас уверяю, книгу эту завтра же приступлю читать. Посмотрел содержание - ахнул, что ранее не взялся за нее. Отложил еще на первом курсе до созревания и профукал вспышку...

Comment: Вы же знаете этот универсальный ответ "depends on":)
А если серьезно, я за Class Table Inheritance(по сути ваш вариант 3), он и держит по полочкам структуру данных и связи можно наладить по обстоятельствам(где нужен FK на абстракцию - значит на абстрактную users, а если только связь присуща на докторов - то на таблицу с докторами)
Оптимизацией уже стоит заниматься после замеров. И да чтобы не попасть в просак с ORM почитайте так же книжки по DDD (например "крассную книгу" Вернон Вона "Реализация методов предметно-ориентированного проектирования")

Comment: И да, если вы это можете сделать, поменяйте теги на более подходящее...потому что это точно не про php и скорее всего касается общего orm, нежели laravel и eloquent. БД можно оставить, так как вопрос оптимизации под конкретную БД остается открытым

Comment: По мне так - вот прекрасный ответ на мой вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691577/how-can-i-implement-single-table-inheritance-using-laravels-eloquent

Comment: Ну а мне ближе Мартин:) кстати в указанном ответе меня смутило описание добавления нового вопроса...как то это противоречит правильному констрейнту отношения 1 к 1. То есть мы должны сначала добавить запись в общей таблице так как именно в ней выдаются идентификаторы, и уже потом этот id пользовать как FK-PK  В конкретной таблице